# Sending linux process to background without pressing enter

Tags: linux

I;m running ethr tool to send TCP Traffic to my device.
The Ethr tools sends traffic per interface and i have written a python script to execute the ethr tool command for multiple interfaces. I chose to run to execute the command in the background so that i can interate through.

The problem that I face is, using ampsersand '&' I'm able to send the process to background but it requires to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to be able to get back the prompt. is there a way to get the prompt without pressing enter?

The command that I use to run the tool is:
`./ethr -s ip 73.3.224.11 -4 -port 10499 -no &`

I tried to redirect to a file but the problem is the file size grows and my VM Crashes.
kindly suggest any alternate solution pls

Comment: Pressing Enter is just the way you finish typing any command line. Why don't you want to type it?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Since i use a python script to execute the command, i tried to use \n but that did not work.

Comment: Enter is just used for entering commands interactively. If you're running the script from Python, it's not needed. `subprocess.Popen()` will run the command in the background without waiting for it to finish.

Comment: Show the Python code you're trying to use.